# jquery - php - get text value by form submit

Tags: jquery, variables, submit, html

i have a small problem regarding jquery/php.
in the last few days i built an interactive game.

excerpt:

```
counter++; 
$("#counter").html("" + counter);
....
```

so the number of clicks is counted by the counter and displayed in a span.

my wish:
how can i make it possible that i get this value of the span by a form submit? the submit goes to another page so my idea was that i make a php variable out of it - but i have no clue how to do that :(

can you PLEASE give me a little hint or help? :)

thank you in advance!

ng jonathan2011

Comment: What are you trying to do with the variable? If you want the value to be persistent, as in living past the life of the script, you will need to either set a session on the user's browser (only he/she will increment the variable, and it will not exist once the browser is closed), or you need to save the variable to a database, then it can be saved indefinitely, and each user can increment it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a hidden input element:

```
<input type="hidden" name="myhiddenvar" id="myhiddenvar" />
```

Assign the value of the counter to the hidden element using jQuery

```
$("#myhiddenvar").val(counter);
```

Grab the value via $_POST or $_GET as such:

```
$counter = $_POST['myhiddenvar'];
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends greatly on what you're doing when the form is submitted. For example, if you are POSTing the form with AJAX, you could do something like this:

```
$.post("yourScript.php", { yourVariable: $("#counter").html() }, function() {
    //Done
});
```

Another option would be to put the value in a hidden field as well as the element that displays it:

```
$("#someHiddenInput").val(counter);
```

The hidden input will  be submitted along with your form in the normal way.

Also, note that you can just do this:

```
$("#counter").html(counter); //No string concatenation
```

Which will still work because JavaScript will coerce the Number type to a String.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want the javascript counter variable available in php script.

So you can send it by ajax:

```
$.get('myscript.php?counter=' + $("#counter").text(), function(data) {
  alert(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure, what your goal is, but you can simply submit it to a php file with AJAX:

```
counter++; 
$.post('file.php', {score:counter}, function(data) {
  $("#counter").html("" + counter);  
});
```

**//file.php:**

```
if(isset($_POST['score']) && !empty($_POST['score'])) {
  $score = $_POST['score'];
  //so something with it...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the counter into data() of the element:

```
$("#counter").html("" + counter).data('counter', counter);
// then
$.ajax({data: {counter: $("#counter").data('counter')} ... });
```

Or

```
$.ajax({data: { counter: parseInt($("#counter").html()) } ... });
```